# What is called when a DbContext is reset when pooling is used?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Is there some method or hook in a `DbContext` to know when it is being reset via context pooling? I'd like to cache some state and clear it out. The [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#dbcontext-pooling) indicate this:

> Avoid using DbContext Pooling if you maintain your own state (for example, private fields) in your derived DbContext class that should not be shared across requests. EF Core will only reset the state that is aware of before adding a DbContext instance to the pool.

How can I make EF Core aware of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after digging through the Entity Framework Code, here's the magic sauce.

- Create a class that implements `IResettableService`
- I did some magic with locking to ensure that its state would remain consistent.
- Register with the `IServiceCollection`:

  ```
  services.AddScoped<ServiceContract, ServiceImplementation>()
          .AddScoped<IResettableService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ServiceContract>());
  ```